# Read an environment variable in the application scope from the host linux system

Tags: c, linux

Good morning,
I have an application in C language that runs on a linux based embedded device.
The business logic set the `TZ` env. variable with the instructions:

```
setenv ("TZ", time_zone_string, 1);
tzset ();
```

Supposing the `time_zone_string` matches the POSIX rules.
The time zone of my application is different from time zone of host system device.

From the host device, can I access to the `TZ` env. variable of application? Without place some `printf()`, `system()` and so on, in the code of application?

Comment: read `/proc/$pid/environ`

Comment: @ZangMingJie Note that will only represent the *initial* state of the process's environment - it won't reflect any changes made by the process itself after it's started.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process

Comment: I don't understand, do you not just need getenv?

Comment: @Joe I'd like read the env outside of application not inside.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thank you for the suggestion

Comment: The easiest way (since it's *your* application) is to explicitly make that available (e.g. by writing a file, or by providing a pipe or socket from which it may be read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can attach the process (or coredump of it) to your debugger, you may search the wanted environment variable from `environ` array.

gdb example:

```
(gdb) print *(environ+10)
$27 = 0xbeb52fb1 "PWD=/"
(gdb) print *(environ+11)
$28 = 0xbeb52fb7 "SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.194.19 55358 192.168.194.21 22"
(gdb) print *(environ+12)
$29 = 0x11850 "ABC=123"
(gdb)
```

There may be easier way to find the correct value. But if you have only few environment variable, then you will find the correct one quite soon.

More info: [Man page of the variable](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)